# if a user has registered in the last 10 days do something

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to create the condition: if a user has registered in the last 10 days do something.

```
var user = new User();
            DateTime time = new DateTime(0);
            if (user.RegisteredAt < time)
            {
                DataAp.Fill(dt);
                dgRecent.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                DataAp.Update(dt);
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Orders in last 10 days ");
            }
```

Comment: I want to give you an answer, but you didn't ask a question

Comment: ...so what's the question?

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more context here chief. Unless a mind reader comes across this question, no one is going to know what your values are or what your methods do....

Comment: Habib is a mind reader!  That explains a LOT! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your check should be:

```
if((DateTime.Now - user.RegisteredAt).TotalDays < 10)
```

Subtracting two `DateTime` objects would give you a `TimeSpan`, you can use its properties like [`TimeSpan.Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the difference in days.

Comment: `Days` is sufficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I never knew there is a `Days` property :)